# Преобразование данных в методе без изменения условия метода

Tags: java, методы

Написать метод который на промежутке [a, b] будет находить числа которые кратны числу n. 
Сигнатура метода `public static int findDivCount(short a, short b, int n)`

Вопрос IDEA ругается что разные типы данных, в условие метода, как их преобразовать что бы не понять условия метода???

```
    public class MethodDivCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((findDivCount(1, 20, 2));
    }

    public static int findDivCount(short a, short b, int n) {


        int count = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % n == 0) {
                count++;
                i += n - 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short используется достаточно редко, тк он спецефичен.
в данном примере лучше его вообще не использовать, но ,если так необходимо, работает такой код с явным приведением

```
System.out.println(findDivCount((short) 1), ((short) 20), 2);
```